# Photo Synching between Catalina and iOS 13 losing settings

Tags: photos, photos.app, catalina

My goal is to overcome my 64gig iPhone's storage limits by creating a smartfolder that contains all my photos except "duplicates".

I am synching between a fully updated iMac (Catalina) and a fully updated iPhone 11 pro/uIS 13.2

In finder on the Mac I request: "Selected Albulms" + "Automatically Include photos from last year". I also choose a SmartFolder called "All except Duplicates" which has one rule, which is "Album is not Duplicate Marked Photos". Duplicate Marked photos is an album generated by "Duplicate Photo Fixer Pro". As far as I can tell it's a normal album.

After synching, when I return to the Finder, the chosen folder is no longer checked and it seems like I have synched just the photos from 1 year back. This is fully reproducible.

So my question is: can you explain the behavior? Is it a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I’m surprised this works as the spotlight criteria is a live search and selective sync would need to be programmed in a sophisticated way to enumerate that folder. I could see that being a bug in the new finder UI sync code. Are you looking for confirmation that this is a bug or for software recommendations how to avoid native syncing? This is a great problem research, but can you edit a clear question what practical task do you want to get an answer to?

Comment: That's a pretty smart answer and it might just be right. My question was whether the behavior I see is expected, or if I was doing something wrong. If your theory is correct then it explains my problem.

Comment: Cool - I probably can’t / won’t try to replicate this, but I’m sure someone else that’s not convinced iCloud photos can easily test this for you.